# Bash - Find changed files in folder compared to latest commit

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to write a `bash` script that work into a `gitlab pipeline` that detect the changed files.
Once, I retrieve the list of folder in the root project, I check if there is a file in the latest commit that are in this folder. If true I upload them into a s3 bucket.

This is my pipeline code:

```
stages:
  - deploy

file-distributions:
  image: python:latest
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - pip install awscli
  script:
    - >
      FILES_IN_FOLDER=$(ls -ad */)
      TO_BE_UPLOADED=()
      CHANGED_FILES=()

      for file in $(git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT $CI_COMMIT_SHA); do
        CHANGED_FILES+=("$file")
      done

      for folder in $FILES_IN_FOLDER; do
        for file in $CHANGED_FILES; do
          if [[ "$file" == *"$folder"* ]]; then 
            TO_BE_UPLOADED+=("$file")
          fi
        done
      done

      echo $TO_BE_UPLOADED
      if [ ${#TO_BE_UPLOADED[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "No files to upload"
        exit 0
      else
        aws s3 sync ./ s3://$S3_BUCKET/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include '"$(echo ${TO_BE_UPLOADED// /,})"'
      fi
```

When the script run into the pipeline I got this error:

> /bin/bash: eval: line 133: syntax error near unexpected token `then'

Where I wrong?

Comment: change `- >` to `- |`. The script has some problems... check it with shellcheck .

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is an option, but GitLab also offers the built-in feature of Artifacts to [automatically upload changed/created files during a pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#add-untracked-files-to-artifacts).

[Artifacts can also be configured to be uploaded to S3](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/job_artifacts.html#using-object-storage). While this is an instance wide configuration, ment to be used to store them in a safe place, you could also use it to retrieve them from there.